# Elementary theme missing arrow in Nautilus

Tags: gnome, nautilus, nautilus-elementary, elementary-theme

I've been using "Elementary Theme" for a while now and i have noticed, that there is a missing arrow at the end of the folder path.

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know why this is happening????

Answer (score 5):

Open Nautilus, then go to `Edit -> Preferences`, choose `Tweaks`tab and check `Show like breadcrumbs`. Now restart Nautilus (in the Terminal write `nautilus -q`), next time you open Nautilus everything will be fine.

Comment: @piole: if the above answer fixed your issue, can you close this question?  You have to click on the checkmark icon (✔)  to confirm the ans is right.